# why gnuplot does not plot after fit?

Tags: plot, output, gnuplot

I am trying to fit a linear curve, and then plot the graph with the fitted line as well. However, the following does not work, as gnuplot makes a 0 kbyte .png output.

```
set t push
set term png
fit f(x) "NET_OUTPUT.dat" u 1:2 via a,b 
plot "NET_OUTPUT.dat" using 1:2 with points, f(x) 
unset output
set term pop
```

If the fit line is not included, I can plot without problem.
I suspect that the problem is that the fit.log file is written, and the gnuplot does not finish the writing of the output file.

Does somebody know what is the problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens if you put your `set output` command after `set term png`? It would be helpful if you provided information on which version of gnuplot you use, which OS, etc. As it stands the code is not a minimal working example--could you provide a small version of the data file with which we could try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Also you don't set any output file.

Comment: he could be redirecting stdout to a file, in which case its likely a system specific issue.

Comment: How have you set `f(x)`?  Have you set an output file or are your redirecting your output?  Do you really need push/pop and if so, why?

Comment: thank you for the comments. I use gp424win32 version on Windows7. Actually, I have the net_sug.gp file with this: GNUTERM = "win"
f(x)=a*x+b
a=1
b=0
ti = sprintf("%.2fx+%.2f", a, b)
fit f(x) "NET_OUTPUT_ketp_bin_3600_mask2.dat" u 1:2 via a,b 
plot "NET_OUTPUT_egyp_ketp_3600_mask_ketp_n_q.dat" using 1:2 with points, f(x) t ti
unset output" I call this form an other file: set t push
set term png
set output "$0"
load "net_sug.gp" 
set output 
set term pop

Answer (score 0):

For gnuplot when plotting to a png I typically create a script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set term png
set output "out.png"

f(x) = a*x + b
fit f(x) "data.dat" u 1:2 via a,b

plot "data.dat" u 1:2, f(x)
```

and call it with `./plot.gnu` or I create a script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set term png

f(x) = a*x + b
fit f(x) "data.dat" u 1:2 via a,b

plot "data.dat" u 1:2, f(x)
```

and call it with `./plot.gnu > out.png`.

The first way asks gnuplot to write a png to the specified output file.  The second ask gnuplot to generate the png but doesn't set a location (so it gets dumped to standard output), in this case I redirect the standard output (in bash with `>`) to my png file.

You can also pass the script into gnuplot with `gnuplot plot.gnu` or `gnuplot plot.gnu > out.png` on the command line in which case the lines beginning with `#` are ignored as comments.